# Android Development - Custom Button Appearance/Behavior

Tags: android, button, android-layout

I am writing an extremely simple Android application.  In doing so, I've found it's quite difficult for me to emulate the button UI elements that are found on the Droid X application selector screen.  For those not familiar, they are an icon with white text beneath them.  The text has a black rounded rectangle behind it and when the button is clicked, the background beneath the icon and text turns red.

My current solution involves StateListDrawables, but then the rounded rectangle has a fixed width, and has to be edited into every button icon.  Localization is an eventual goal, so my solution is temporary at best.  I assume there's a less stupid way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, and I've never seen the button you're talking about. But the process should be something similar.

First you create your drawables (the actual background images). One with the red background and one transparent. Your drawable XML would look something like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_bg_red"/>
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_bg_red"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_bg_pressed"/>
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

Then your button itself can be declared similar to this:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/droid_x_btn"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Droid Does"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/btn_icon" <!-- this is for the icon on top -->
                android:background="@drawable/ic_droid_x_button" <!-- The name of the above file without extension -->
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Heh, that's almost exactly what I have, but yours is more elegant.  I think this'll work as a solution, even if the black bar behind the text won't be adjustable.  Thank you very much, sir.  :)